# automatically closing a resource passed as an argument

Tags: java, autocloseable

If I want to automatically close a resource passed as an argument, is there a more elegant solution than this?

```
void doSomething(OutputStream out) {

  try (OutputStream closeable = out) {
    // do something with the OutputStream
  }
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to have this resource closed automatically, without declaring another variable `closeable` that refers to the same object as `out`.

### Aside

I realise that closing `out` within `doSomething` is considered a bad practice

Comment: I think the `doSomething` method should not close the input stream itselft. The caller should take care of it.

Comment: I believe java 9 allows that (the `out` variable is effectively final). But there's a risk for method parameters, I think.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik It does implement `AutoCloseable`, from the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html): _"All Implemented Interfaces: Closeable, Flushable, AutoCloseable". It directly implements `Closeable` which extends `AutoCloseable`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I can see another picture in my sources. Probably it depends on JVM version.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik Only if you're using Java 6 or lower. `AutoCloseable` was introduced in Java 7. Or maybe you've overlooked that `Closeable` is a sub-interface of `AutoCloseable`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Java 9 and higher, you can do

```
void doSomething(OutputStream out) {
  try (out) {
    // do something with the OutputStream
  }
}
```

This is only allowed if `out` is final or effectively final. See also the [Java Language Specification version 10 14.20.3. try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3).

Comment: I'm using Java 8 at the moment, but good to know there's a more elegant solution in the next version

Comment: @Dónal The only thing in Java 8 that would make your current code (as shown) shorter is replacing `OutputStream closeable` by `Closeable closeable`, but I think that is grasping at straws and makes the intent even less obvious.

Answer (score 3):

I use Java 8 and it does not support Resource Reference. What about create universal method that accepts `Closable` and payload:

```
public static <T extends Closeable> void doAndClose(T out, Consumer<T> payload) throws Exception {
    try {
        payload.accept(out);
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Client code could look like this:

```
OutputStream out = null;

doAndClose(out, os -> {
    // do something with the OutputStream
});

InputStream in = null;

doAndClose(in, is -> {
    // do something with the InputStream
});
```

Comment: Can you include an example how this would be applied (eg as a replacement in the `doSomething` method)?

Comment: This removes the potential confusion that might arise from 2 references to the closeable resource being accessible within the payload body. It should probably accept a `Consumer<? super T>`, though.

Answer (score -4):

```
void doSomething(OutputStream out) {
  try {
    // do something with the OutputStream
  }
  finally {
    org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.closeQuietly(out);
  }
}
```

Comment: From the [JavaDocs of org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.ArrayUtils.closeQuietly](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#closeQuietly-java.io.OutputStream-): "**Deprecated.** As of 2.6 removed without replacement. Please use the try-with-resources statement or handle suppressed exceptions manually."